# Spring Batch: Need a better job configuration

Tags: spring-batch

My Spring batch app processes 1 of 5 different types of files. The flow is exactly the same for all 5 types. The configuration I have is rather long and unwieldy. Can someone help me to compact it some by maybe reusing flows?

This is the best I could come up with:

```java
        return jobBuilderFactory.get(CommonConstants.BATCH_JOB_DISTRIBUTION)
                .listener(jobListener)
                .start(retrieveFileStep())
                .next(createFileJobDetailStep(fileJobDetailTasklet))
                .next(fileTypeDecider)

                .from(fileTypeDecider).on(FileType.YearEnd.name()).to(yearEndStep)
                .from(yearEndStep).on("ERROR").to(moveFileToErrorStep(fileOperationsTasklet))
                .from(yearEndStep).on("SUCCESS").to(moveFileToProcessedStep(fileOperationsTasklet))

                .from(fileTypeDecider).on(FileType.Quarterly.name()).to(quarterlyStep)
                .from(quarterlyStep).on("ERROR").to(moveFileToErrorStep(fileOperationsTasklet))
                .from(quarterlyStep).on("SUCCESS").to(moveFileToProcessedStep(fileOperationsTasklet))

                //[repeat 3 more times...]
```

I'd love a better way to write this. Thanks.

Comment: This is sequentially executing instead create as separate job or with partitioner  based on filetype.

Comment: No, it’s not sequential. There will only be one file type per job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a sub-flow, and reusing that sub-flow throughout the job configuration.

```
public Flow flow(String flowName, Step step, Tasklet fileOperationsTasklet) {
    return new FlowBuilder<Flow>(flowName)
            .start(step)
            .from(step).on("ERROR").to(moveFileToErrorStep(fileOperationsTasklet))
            .from(step).on("SUCCESS").to(moveFileToProcessedStep(fileOperationsTasklet))
            .end();
}
```

So now my configuration includes:

```
.from(fileTypeDecider).on(FileType.YearEnd.name()).to(flow("yearEndFlow", yearEndStep, fileOperationsTasklet))
```